# Add option "ask a new question" to page not found

Tags: feature-request, questions, asking-questions, deleted-questions, 404-not-found

The page "Page not found [newline] This question was removed from Stack Overflow for reasons of moderation." list various options how to continue but fails to list the option to ask the same question, with a fresh question body and, if possible, higher quality title. I suggest adding this:

> If the question is not off-topic and you feel you can describe the question to the quality standards expected on this site please ask the question once more.

I understand the body of a question can render it unsalvageable and the best option is to close it. However, the title in the URL that still is indexed by external search engines brings these "page not found" pages to surface for cases where the title visible in the URL is a perfectly valid, good quality, on-topic question when the user's search query matches it well.

Comment: What we need _more_ of is users being directed to _search, research, read the docs, read the specs, read the FAQ, read the guidelines_, and **not** _ask a new question_. I.e. something more in line with [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/4642212).

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately such advice would usually be counterproductive.

Generally we delete unsalvageable questions. Asking an unsalvageable question again will simply result in the same action, i.e., closure and deletion. So advising people to ask it again would just result in additional frustration.

Generally, closure and deletion is based on the body rather than the title. After all, we can clean up the title if it doesn't match the body. A great title with a terrible body is pretty unusual. All we can really do with that is close it and see if the OP improves it.

If you really think the question is salvageable you can always edit it and then flag it for undeletion. If you asked the question, you can always view and edit it, even if it's deleted. If you deleted it, you'll have to undelete it first in order to edit it, but if it wasn't you then you can edit it while it's deleted.

Comment: What fraction of users have the necessary 10,000 reputation? What is the likelihood of one of them being interested in a rare, very specific technical problem and coming across the closed question?

Comment: @JoachimWagner, 17M / [24900](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/980060/all-users-with-moderator-tools) = 682.73 or 0.1464%. --- [That comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376987/add-option-ask-a-new-question-to-page-not-found/376988#comment1256576_376988) is a new question. Deleted questions show up in the [tag:10k-tools].